# How to find files in different specific folders?

Tags: spotlight, folders, search

I have several folders named "auto_saves" around my hard drive. I want to make smart search to find all image files from all folders named "auto_saves". But how?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think this is possible in Finder.

You can get the desired search result using [HoudahSpot](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/). HoudahSpot is a third party file search tool that uses the existing Spotlight index. Full disclosure: I am the developer of HoudahSpot.

With HoudahSpot you can search in several folders at once. This would however require that you list all “auto_saves” folders you want to search.

I recommend, you search for image files in HoudahSpot and then use the “path filter” feature to show only search results where the file path contains “/auto_saves”. In HoudahSpot you will find the filter field right above the list of search results. Set it to “Filter by Path” and enter “/auto_saves”.

You can save your HoudahSpot search as a template so you can return to it later.